# Read Third Party Cookie in Javascript and Server

Tags: javascript, cookies, browser

if a domain `foo.com` has cookie `bar=1`, cookie was placed when the domain been visited as first party.
(so, the assumption is: the cookie is already there, not session cookie, not http-only, cookie under root"`/`". This question is not about write cookie, it is about read.)

Also, the browser disabled the 3rd party cookie and no other plugins, just a clean installed browser with 3rd party disabled. No P3P header on `foo.com` as well.

Upon above condition, my questions are:

When page `foo.com/somepage.html` has been placed in an iframe under a different domain (third party)

1. Will the browser send the cookie `bar=1` to server when read the page?
2. Can the JavaScript in the page read the cookie `bar=1`?
3. Will I expect any browser difference on above two scenarios?

**Additional Question**

I do not need the answer because I do not use this scenario but curious to know.

Will the browser update the cookie (quite like write) under above condition if read is possible(, and old cookie is there, just need update (not a new write))?

Comment: But the page has been placed in an iFrame on a different domain, which quite 3rd-party cookie to me.

Comment: Ah I see - sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1.) Will the browser send the cookie bar=1 to server when read the page?

Yes.

> 2.) Can the JavaScript in the page read the cookie bar=1?

That will depend on whether or not it is a session cookie (created with the [`HttpOnly`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#HttpOnly_cookie) flag). If it is a session cookie you cannot read it from javascrit. It will be sent to the server though on `foo.com` and a server side script will be able to read it.

> 3.) Will I expect any browser difference on above two scenarios?

No.

Of course all of the above apply to the `foo.com` domain inside the iframe. The containing HTML page and server have 0 access to this cookie.

Comment: Thanks. Will the browser that works include IE6? Btw, I update my questions and ask an additional one, which I expect the answer is no however.

Comment: IE6! WOW! I guess the answer is yes but to be honest I am not quite sure. I can hardly consider IE6 as a browser. If you need to support it, I'd recommend you testing the scenario. As far as your additional question is concerned I must confess that I didn't understand it.

Comment: I want to try at IE6, just cannot find it :( I do not even know how to get an IE6 these days, but as support it, not really ,just have to think about it. Just forget the additional question, it must be no anyway.

Comment: www.browserstack.com will let you test on IE6.

Comment: After some test, I think 1) should be no. The cookie set by first party will not send to server when it serve as third party, but the js on page can read it.